# retrieve data and return it in a tree structure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have some code here in coldfusion that retrieves my organisation's structure using a basic for loop

**example:**

```
level1 = retrieveOrgs(1);
for loop level1
    <span>level1.description</span>
    level2 = retrieveOrgs(level1.orgId);
    for loop level2
        <span>level2.description</span>
        level3 = retrieveOrgs(level1.orgId);
        for loop level3
            ....
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I am moving the webapp to java using spring/hibernate combo. And I'm wondering if there is a "better" way of doing this in Java/Spring/Hibernate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define an entity like the following, and you'll have a tree structure:

```
@Entity
public class Org {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Org> childrenOrgs;
    ...
}
```